# How to plot the breakdown of film genre releases by year

Tags: r

I want to make a stacked area graph that shows the proportion of the genre of films released per year. Struggling to wrangle the data correctly (hopefully once I understand how to correctly format the data I can make the graph). How do I make it so I have the number of releases of each genre by year?

My data frame should show the year and then x number of releases were drama, y number were mystery, and so on.

For simplicity I have filtered to find the most common genres, however the filter here isn't behaving as expected.

After having filtered the variable I'm unsure of where to go next.

Struggling to conceptualise the steps but hopefully this is clear enough...
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

ratings <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-01-08/IMDb_Economist_tv_ratings.csv")
ratings$year_rel <-year(ratings$date)


ratings %>%
  count(genres) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  filter(n > 100)

desired_genres <- c("Comedy, Drama", "Drama", "Action, Crime, Drama", "Action, Adventure, Drama", "Crime", "Drama")

ratings %>%
  select(genres, year_rel) %>%
  filter(genres %in% desired_genres) #this only shows the drama genre

#Unsure where to go from here so as to break down the releases by genre.
```

Comment: Not sure what your goal is. Clearly, the `genres` column is multi-tagged. And you've replicated that in your `desired_genres`. Do you want to break them out by *individual* genre? Or are you happy with the groupings, with `"Action, Crime, Drama"` being different than `"Drama"` and `"Crime"`? You say *films*, but looking at the data it appears to be TV, where each season has it's own row. I would recommend looking at a small subset of data, e.g., `ratings[1:20, ]`, and thinking carefully (and explaining clearly!) about what you want the result to be for that small illustrative subset.

Comment: Look at the unique values of genres: they're formatted as `"Action,Crime,Drama"`, not `"Action, Crime, Drama"`. This is a typo. Good to study your data before you try working with it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're almost there. Your filter isn't behaving as expected because in the data, the genre column doesn't have spaces and your `desired_genres` vector does have spaces. Rather than re-typing what you see, avoid bugs by programmatically extracting the desired genres, by using `pull(genres)` to the end of your pipeline and assign the result to your `desired_genres` vector.

Then add a `group_by` and an `add_count`:

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

ratings <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-01-08/IMDb_Economist_tv_ratings.csv")
ratings$year_rel <-year(ratings$date)


desired_genres <- ratings %>%
  count(genres) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  filter(n > 100) %>%
  pull(genres)

filtered_rating <- ratings %>%
  select(genres, year_rel) %>%
  filter(genres %in% desired_genres) %>%
  group_by(year_rel) %>%
  add_count(genres)
```

Comment: Sorry I appreciate my question wasn’t particularly clear. Thanks both for your help.